# Using Tab key to indent code in Eclipse Kepler under Mac

Tags: eclipse, macos

When I was working under Windows or Linux, pressing Tab key in Eclipse would indent and shif-tab would un-indent code. I work on a Mac now and pressing Tab does nothing (Eclipse Kepler).

More than that: when I press Tab key inside Eclipse editor, the next pressed key is ignored. I tested this in PyDev and PHP environments.

What might be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solutions:

1) Try to uninstall your ***kepler*** distribution and pull another from here http://www.eclipse.org/kepler/, you must have some key binding that must had came along with your distribution.

2) Also if you go to menu Eclipse > Preferences > General > Keys you can try  to understand where is your conflicting command, maybe tab is associated with more commands than just the 'Indent Line', which could cause that behavior.

Note: There is absolutely nothing wrong with Tab Key on Eclipse Kepler, over OSX (I've a Mac too and it works perfectly).

I exported a [CSV](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pio4bunouwfjs3f/pinho-keys.csv) with my default key bindings, just in case you want to check out an working version .

Also make sure you don't have any specific shortcut on your OSX Keyboard Configuration targeting the Tab Key, you can check this on OSX Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts.

Comment: The original problem was (as it turns out) that I re-mapped content assistant from cmd-space (which is switches keyboard layout) to Tab-space. Thank you for the tip